# TypeError: (0, _app.initializeApp) is not a function

Tags: react-native, firebase-realtime-database, react-native-firebase

[image: error description]
The app is just about taking data from text inputs and then uploading them on realtime database. It was working fine, but after I imported drawer navigator, it started giving the error above. I removed the dependency, but still it gives the same error..
I am new to react native...

```
//config.js
`import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app'
import { getDatabase } from 'firebase/database'
  function StartFirebase(){
    const firebaseConfig = {
      apiKey: "",
      authDomain: "",
      databaseURL: "",
      projectId: "",
      storageBucket: "",
      messagingSenderId: "",
      appId: ""
  };
  const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  return getDatabase(app);

}
export default StartFirebase;
`


Below is the code of the main screen which contains the code for textinput and uploading data to database
```

//createScreen.js

```
`import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  SafeAreaView,
  Platform,
  StatusBar,
  Image,
  ScrollView,
  TextInput,
  Dimensions,
  Button,
  Alert
} from "react-native";

import { RFValue } from "react-native-responsive-fontsize";
import AppLoading from "expo-app-loading";
import * as Font from "expo-font";
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/core";

import {ref,set,get,update,remove,child} from 'firebase/database'
import StartFirebase from "./config";
const initialState = {
  name: "",
  phoneNumber: "",
  workYouDo: "",
  price: "",
};
let customFonts = {
  "Bubblegum-Sans": require('./BubblegumSans-Regular.ttf')
};

export default class CreateScreen extends Component {
    
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        fontsLoaded: false,
        name: "a",
        phoneNumber: "0000000000",
        workYouDo: "a",
        price: "a",
        db:''
    };
  }

  async _loadFontsAsync() {
    await Font.loadAsync(customFonts);
    this.setState({ fontsLoaded: true });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this._loadFontsAsync();
    this.setState({
      db:StartFirebase()
    });
  }
 addStory() {
    let phoneNumberLength = this.state.phoneNumber.length
    if (
      this.state.name &&
      this.state.phoneNumber &&
      this.state.workYouDo &&
      this.state.price 
      &&
      phoneNumberLength == 10
    ) {
      let storyData = {
        name: this.state.name,
        phoneNumber: this.state.phoneNumber,
        workYouDo: this.state.workYouDo,
        price: this.state.price,
      };
      const db = this.state.db;
      set(ref(db,'users/'+this.state.name),
      {
        storyData
      })
      .then(()=>{alert('data was added')})
      this.props.navigation.navigate('Home')
      this.setState(initialState)
    } else {
      
      Alert.alert(
        "All fields are required!",
        'Phone number should be of 10 digits without +91'
      
      );
    }
  }

    

  render() {
    if (!this.state.fontsLoaded) {
      return <AppLoading />;
    } else {
    
      return (
        <View
            style={styles.container}
        >
          <SafeAreaView style={styles.droidSafeArea} />
          <View style={styles.appTitle}>
            <View style={styles.appIcon}>
             
            </View>
            <View style={styles.appTitleTextContainer}>
              <Text
                style={
                  styles.appTitleText
                }
              >
                Your Details
              </Text>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.fieldsContainer}>
            <ScrollView>
             

              
                
              <View style={{ marginHorizontal: RFValue(10) }}>
                <TextInput
                  style={
                     styles.inputFont
                  }
                  onChangeText={text => this.setState({name:text})}
                  placeholder={"Name"}
                  placeholderTextColor={'white'}
                   
                  value = {this.state.name}
                  
    
               />
               <TextInput
                  style={[
                   styles.inputFont,
                    styles.inputFontExtra,
                    styles.inputTextBig
                  ]}
                  onChangeText={text => this.setState({phoneNumber:text})}
                  placeholder={"PhoneNumber (Without +91)"}
                  multiline={true}
                  numberOfLines={1}
                  maxLength={10}
                  minLength = {10}
                  type = {Number}
                  keyboardType={"number-pad"}
                
                  placeholderTextColor={
                    'white'
                  }
                  value = {this.state.phoneNumber}
                  />
                  
            
                <TextInput
                  style={[
                     styles.inputFont,
                    styles.inputFontExtra,
                    styles.inputTextBig
                  ]}
                  onChangeText={text => this.setState({workYouDo:text})}
                  placeholder={"WorkYouDo"}
                  multiline={true}
                  numberOfLines={3}
                  placeholderTextColor={
                    'white'
                  }
                  value = {this.state.workYouDo}
                  
                />
                <TextInput
                  style={[
                    
                    styles.inputFont,
                    styles.inputFontExtra,
                    styles.inputTextBig
                  ]}
                  onChangeText={text => this.setState({price:text})}
                  placeholder={"price"}
                  multiline={false}
                  numberOfLines={1}
                  placeholderTextColor={
                    'white'
                  }
                  value = {this.state.price}
                  
                />
              </View>
              <View style={styles.submitButton}>
                <Button
                
          title="Submit"
                  color="#841584"
                  onPress={() => this.addStory()}
                  
                />
              </View>
            </ScrollView>
          </View>
          <View style={{ flex: 0.08 }} />
        </View>
      );
    }

  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#15193c"
  },
//   containerLight: {
//     flex: 1,
//     backgroundColor: "white"
//   },
  droidSafeArea: {
    marginTop: Platform.OS === "android" ? StatusBar.currentHeight : RFValue(35)
  },
  appTitle: {
    flex: 0.07,
    flexDirection: "row"
  },
  appIcon: {
    flex: 0.3,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },

  appTitleTextContainer: {
    flex: 0.7,
    justifyContent: "center"
  },
  appTitleText: {
    color: "white",
    fontSize: RFValue(28),
    fontFamily: "Bubblegum-Sans"
  },
//   appTitleTextLight: {
//     color: "black",
//     fontSize: RFValue(28),
//     fontFamily: "Bubblegum-Sans"
//   },
  fieldsContainer: {
    flex: 0.85
  },

  inputFont: {
    height: RFValue(40),
    borderColor: "white",
    borderWidth: RFValue(1),
    borderRadius: RFValue(10),
    paddingLeft: RFValue(10),
    color: "white",
    fontFamily: "Bubblegum-Sans"
  },
//   inputFontLight: {
//     height: RFValue(40),
//     borderColor: "black",
//     borderWidth: RFValue(1),
//     borderRadius: RFValue(10),
//     paddingLeft: RFValue(10),
//     color: "black",
//     fontFamily: "Bubblegum-Sans"
//   },


  inputFontExtra: {
    marginTop: RFValue(15)
  },
  inputTextBig: {
    textAlignVertical: "top",
    padding: RFValue(5)
  },
  submitButton: {
    marginTop: RFValue(20),
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center"
  }
});
```

`
PlZZ HElP

I have tried different ways of importing firebase, but none helped, I was expecting the error to go away but if intialize app would go then getData variable is not defined would appear..